# How to lowecase only first word in the sentence?

Tags: swift

I have a text "Hello Word" "Word Hello",
How can i get "hello Word" "word Hello" (for example)

'''

let string1 = "Hello Word"
let referenceString1 = "hello Word"

let string2 = "Word Hello"
let referenceString2 = "word Hello"

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get first letter of the first word and make it lowercase , then remove first letter and add the rest.

```
extension StringProtocol {
var lowerCaseFirts: String { prefix(1).lowercased() + dropFirst() }
}

let str = "Hello World"
print(str.lowerCaseFirts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(sentence : str) -> str:
    words = sentence.split()

    if not (words[0])[0].islower():
        words[0] = (words[0])[0].lower() + (words[0])[1:]

    out = " ".join(words)

    return out    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence1 = "Hello Everyone"
    out1 = fun(sentence1)
    print(sentence1, " : ", out1)

    sentence2 = "HOW ARE YOU"
    out2 = fun(sentence2)
    print(sentence2, " : ", out2)
```

Output:

```
Hello Everyone  :  hello Everyone
HOW ARE YOU  :  hOW ARE YOU
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer works perfectly for the OPs use case:

`Hello Word`

However, if we are speaking about first word in a sentence, there could be a more complex string with multiple sentences:

`Hello Word. JELLO world? WEllo Word.\n ZEllo world! MeLLow lord.`

In such a case, using REGEX might also work to solve both the scenarios.

Someone with more savvy REGEX skills might be able to improve the REGEX

```
extension String
{
    func withLowerCaseSentences() -> String
    {
        do
        {
            // A sentence is something that starts after a period, question mark,
            // exclamation followed by a space. This is only not true for the first
            // sentence
            //
            // REGEX to capture this
            // (?:^|(?:[.!?]\\s+))
            // Exclude group to get the starting character OR
            // anything after a period, exclamation, question mark followed by a
            // whitespace (space or optional new line)
            //
            // ([A-Z])
            // Capture group to capture all the capital characters
            let regexString = "(?:^|(?:[.!?]\\s+))([A-Z])"
            
            // Initialize the regex
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString,
                                                options: .caseInsensitive)
            
            // Convert string to a character array
            var characters = Array(self)
            
            // Loop through all the regex matches
            for match in regex.matches(in: self,
                                       options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(),
                                       range: NSRange(location: 0,
                                                      length: count))
                as [NSTextCheckingResult]
            {
                // We are not looking for the match, but for the group
                // For example Hello Word. JELLO word will give give us two matches
                // "H" and ". J" but each of the groups within each match
                // will give us what we want which is "H" and "J" so we check if we
                // have a group. Look up matches and groups to learn more
                if match.numberOfRanges > 1
                {
                    // Get the range (location and length) of first group from
                    // the regex match
                    let matchedRange = match.range(at: 1)
                    
                    // Get the capital character at the start of the sentence we found
                    let characterToReplace = characters[matchedRange.location]
                    
                    // Replace the capital letter with a lower cased latter
                    characters[matchedRange.location]
                        = Character(characterToReplace.lowercased())
                }
            }
            
            // Convert the processed character array back to a string if needed
            return String(characters)
        }
        catch
        {
            // handle errors
            print("error")
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Then it can be used:

```
let simpleString = "Hello world"

print("BEFORE")
print(simpleString)
print("\nAFTER")
print(simpleString.withLowerCaseSentences())

let complexString 
  = "Hello Word. JELLO world? WEllo Word.\n ZEllo world! MeLLow lord."

print("\nBEFORE")
print(complexString)
print("\nAFTER")
print(complexString.withLowerCaseSentences())
```

This gives the output:

```
BEFORE
Hello world

AFTER
hello world

BEFORE
Hello Word. JELLO world? WEllo Word.
 ZEllo world! MeLLow lord.

AFTER
hello Word. jELLO world? wEllo Word.
 zEllo world! meLLow lord.
```